# Specifing order of lattice plot panels

Tags: r, lattice

I have looked at the two similar questions on this topic but do not find the answer I'm looking for in either of the two. The as.table function alters the alphabetic sequence from starting in the lower left to starting in the upper left but does nothing about the order of panes within the group.

The data (which are proprietary to my client) have station identifications that are a combination of letters and numbers. When there is a series of sites with the same initial letters within the group of all sites being plotted, they sort by first digit rather than the way we humans count. For example, SW-1, SW-10, SW-11, SW-2, SW-3. I would like them in the order SW-1, SW-2, SW-3, SW-10, SW-11. The code I use is:

```
 xyplot(as.d$quant ~ as.d$sampdate | as.d$site, ylim=range(as.d$quant), xlim=range(as.d$sampdate), 
 main='Arsenic By Time', ylab='Concentraion (mg/L)', xlab='Time')
```

I do not know how to attach a .pdf of the resulting plot but will do so if someone shows me how to do this.

Comment: Generally it is better to post PNG versions. When you have an edit window open there will be green square icon to the right of the `{}` icon that will let you upload a file from your computer.

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify the levels of that factor variable in the sequence you expect. The default is lexigraphic as you noticed:

```
xyplot(as.d$quant ~ as.d$sampdate | factor( as.d$site, 
                                            levels=1:length(unique(as.d$site))) , 
         ylim=range(as.d$quant),   xlim=range(as.d$sampdate), 
         main='Arsenic By Time', ylab='Concentration (mg/L)', xlab='Time')
```

Based on how the question currently stands, you might need:

```
require(gtools)
xyplot(as.d$quant ~ as.d$sampdate | factor( as.d$site, 
                                  levels=mixedsort( as.character(unique(as.d$site)) ) ) , 
         ylim=range(as.d$quant),   xlim=range(as.d$sampdate), 
         main='Arsenic By Time', ylab='Concentration (mg/L)', xlab='Time')
```

Comment: Thank you, David. For now I'll re-order the sites in the text file and re-read them into R.

Comment: Yes. And do use the `mixedsort` function in gtools. My answer above was based on what you earlier posted on Rhelp which is different than what now appears above.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of points here.

First is that in R things like the order of factor levels are considered to be a property or attribute of the data rather than a property of the graph/analysis.  Because of that there is not generally arguments in the plotting or analysis functions for specifying the order, rather you specify that order in the data object itself, then all plots and analyses use that order.

To change the order you can specify the desired order using the `factor` function, or you can use functions like `relevel` and `reorder` to change the order of the levels of a factor.  If you want the levels to be in the same order that they appear in the data then the `unique` function works well.  For sorting with characters and numbers mixed the `mixedsort` function in the gtools package can be useful.

Comment: Thank you, Greg. It is obvious now that you pointed out that I need to sort the data either prior to reading it into R or use one of the available functions.

Comment: Not exactly. Sorting the data will not do anything. You need to restructure your factor variable.